# Excel Macro find and copy corresponding cell apply formula on the value

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am new to VBA script. I have the following problem.

Sheet 1

```
Date    Sum of cnt

01-04-2014  77 
01-06-2014  3 
01-07-2014  2 
01-08-2014  1
01-09-2014  921
```

Sheet 2

```
Date       count  (count/sumofcout(sheet1)

01-06-2014  3
01-09-2014  4
01-09-2014  712
01-07-2014   1
01-08-2014   1
01-09-2014  205 .....
```

I have to search for the every single date from sheet 1 if there is match in sheet 2 , corresponding count(sheet2)/sum0fcount of that date(sheet1) should be my third column in sheet 2. Please anyone help me. I have large data multiple values of each day in a month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP() for this.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim has suggested in his comment above...you can use Vlookup/Match (along with SumIF) to get your results. A formula like this (with different ranges) should do the job:

IF( ISNA(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!*$A$2:$A$13*,0)),"",B2/SUMIF(Sheet1!$*A$2:$A$13*,A2,Sheet1!*$B$2:$B$13*))

You can change the Ranges A2:A13, B2:B13 to adjust this according to your data